# Result from one query to another

Tags: mysql

```
Table 1

ID  Subject         category

1   news             category1
2   entertainment    category2
3   sport            category3
4   Home             category4


Table 2

ID    Name     Subject

1     mark      sport
2     mark      entertainment
3     David     sport
4     Fred      Home
```

I need the rows FROM table 1 that mark in table 2 corresponds to. In other words I need row 2 and row 3 as a result from table 1. I need to look at table 2 before I know what to get in table 1. I would like Mark to choose the outcome of rows in table 1. I would appreciate any help i can get? (using MySQL btw)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple join, using subject as the key.

```
 Select * from table2 inner join table1 on table2.Subject = table1.Subject where table2.Name = 'Mark'
```

Which will get you (one line example):

```
table2.ID | table2.Name | table2.Subject | table1.ID | table1.Subject | table1.category
     1         Mark          sport           3                sport        category3
```

Comment: much appreciated. so simple once you see the answer. Thanks again

Comment: any time you want to restrict data from one table to include that in another, a join should be first in your mind, as it is easy to do.  Subqueries also work (e.g. select * from table1 where subject in (select subject from table 2 where name = 'mark')

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table2 b
               WHERE  a.subject = b.subject and b.name= 'mark')
```